# Removing dependencies from a Makefile

Tags: makefile

We have scripts that use [gccmakedep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gccmakedep), which fill up the Makefile with dependencies based on the system it was last run on.

How can we make the `clean` target in the Makefile automatically remove the dependencies that gccmakedep has added to the Makefile?

(I cannot have a command in the `clean` target that searches itself for the `"# DO NOT DELETE"` divider, as gccmakedep itself will find that argument and think that's where it should chop...?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can make `gccmakedep -fdepends.mk` produce output into a different makefile. Then you can include it, and remove on clean rule.

```
-include depends.mk
clean:
    @rm -f depends.mk
```

Personally, I use `cc -MMD -MP` to generate `.d` depends and include them in the Makefile. It doesn't need any extra tools and you can clean the `.d` files along with the object files. Here's [an example](https://github.com/CZNIC-Labs/knot-resolver/blob/master/platform.mk#L35).

This is also a [good writeup](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html) by Scott McPeak for more portable solutions and explanation.

Comment: `clean` shouldn't depend on depends.mk in your example - otherwise it will try to build depends.mk before doing a clean, which is a waste of time.  Instead, do `@rm -f depends.mk` as your recipe, so it won't die if the file does not exist yet, and have `clean` dependent on nothing.

Comment: Sure, why not. It depends on what do you want to do. I guess it's more confusing than illustrative for some people.

Answer (score 1):

if possible, avoid modifying your Makefile (and thus dump `gccmakedep`). instead use external files for [dependency tracking](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html).

Alternatively use a script in your clean-rule that does the cleanup (so `gccmakedep` is not triggered directly)